# How to make an unresponsive table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I wanted to know how I can make an unresponsive table as it needs about 40 columns on screen.

My client doesn't mind if they have to horizontally scroll to view the table as long as all of the data is there.

So how do I make an unresponsive table where I set manually what the column widths are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a min-width on the th columns. Here is an example:

http://jsbin.com/xuzuwuko/3/edit

Comment: If you give your table another class (such as the "unresponsive" one I used in the jsbin), or add min-width to the current class for your table that should work without issue.

Also in the future it'd be best if you include your own example, so people can see what exactly you are doing. Without that, your question is not likely to get as much attention.

Answer (score 2):

change the container class for "container-fluid"

Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<table class="table">
...
</table>
</div>
```

for this work is necessary set doctype in html5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and add to header this meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[See documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a variety of ways:

1) set min-width in style-sheet to `table`, `th`, `td`, `tr`:

```
table {
    min-width:700px;
}
tr {
    min-width:120px;
}
th,td {
    min-width:20px;
}
```

2) Or, you can remove header responsive meta view:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of add *min-width* to all `th` element, using style/css include globally.

```
th {
 min-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score -8):

I have found the solution.

I added a `min-width` to all of my heading `th` elements:

```
<th style='min-width: 100px;'>
```

and that seems to work.

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer given by @user3711852 above.

Comment: As a best practice, you should separate your styling from your html.  I would suggest following @user3711852's advice as well.

Comment: This answer was given by someone else. You should have awarded him/her.

Comment: Ah yes I guess it is the same.